# need to update image file in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, c#-4.0

1. I have  800-1000 Uniquely named folders in one large folder.
2. Inside of each uniquely named folder is another folder called /images.
3. And inside of each image folder is a file named "Rock-Star-Site-Design-{UNIQUEFOLDERNAME}-ca-logo.png"
4. I  write a code that replaces all .png files (while keeping the original name) from a .png file which I  supply.

The folder structure and filenames need to remain the same.  Basically i am   updating the old file with a new file, using the same (unique) name, 800-1000 times.

The code i have tried working properly but there is one mistake.There are plenty of images inside Image folder,But i need to update only "Rock-Star-Site-Design-{UNIQUEFOLDERNAME}-ca-logo.png"file every folder.

is there any way so i can get file.startwith("Rock-Star").So i can update particular file i want.

Here is my code:

```
private List<String> DirSearch(string sDir)
{
    List<String> files = new List<String>();
    try
    {
        foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(sDir))
        {
            files.Add(f);



        }
        foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sDir))
        {
            files.AddRange(DirSearch(d));
        }


        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(file))
            {
                File.Copy(Server.MapPath("ca-logo.jpg"), file,true);

            }
        }


    }
    catch (System.Exception excpt)
    {
        //MessageBox.Show(excpt.Message);
    }

    return files;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get the file name from file full path using `Path.GetFileName()`. Then Use `StartsWith()`. When you add files to the list check if the file name starts with the name you want and then add to the list.

```
List<String> files = new List<String>();
foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(""))
{
   //Get file name from full file path
   string fileName = Path.GetFileName(f);

   //Get only the files starts with Rock-Star
   if (fileName.StartsWith("Rock-Star"))
      {
          files.Add(f);
      }

}
```

**EDIT**

If you want to update the files with both upper and lower case lettes then you have to pass `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` enumeration to your `StartsWith()` method

```
  //Get only the files starts with Rock-Star or rock-start 
  if (fileName.StartsWith("Rock-Star",StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
      {
         files.Add(f);
      }
```

**EDIT**

To get files within all sub directories and replace, Pass `SearchOption.AllDirectories` to the GetFiles() method. Following code will search all the sub directories for files with `.png` extension

```
foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(sDir, "*.png", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
```

Comment: i have 2 images like  rock-star and Rock-Star...but i want to update Rock-Star....so what should i have to do for case sensitivity..

Comment: Same code should work, Above code will only update the file with upper case name "Rock - Start". It will not replace "rock - star"

Comment: you right..same code is working....now i got one more problem..i have folder structure like this: mainfolder>subfolder inside this subfolder there are 3 folders.1)css2)images3)php......by using this code i got only css folder but i want to access images folder...        foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sDir))
            {
                files.AddRange(DirSearch(d));
            }

Comment: you right..same code is working....now i got one more problem..i have folder structure like this: mainfolder>subfolder inside this subfolder there are 3 folders.1)css2)images3)php......by using this code i got only css folder but i want to access images folder... foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sDir)) { files.AddRange(DirSearch(d)); }

Answer (score 4):

You can use this to get files based on a regular expression

```
Directory.GetFiles(sDir, "Rock-Star*.png");
```

Rock-Star*.png means files starting with Rock-Star, * means any character or sequence of characters, ending with .png